# dynamic string replace in scala

Tags: string, scala, replace

I have an example string below. Need to do string replace and add _tmp in the original string.
Can someone please help ?

```
Ex: 1    "name,name|substr(city,53,17),coun"
Ex :2    "age,age|substr(zip,10,16),zipcode|substr(street,19,20),place"
```

Expected result:

```
Expected Answer 1 : "name,name|city_tmp,coun"
Expected Answer 2 : "age,age|zip_tmp,zipcode|street_tmp,place"
```

Currently I am splitting the original string and doing for loop to match each string contains the word "substr" and replacing it with spaces.

Then further I split that element and create an array and replace the first element of the array with _tmp.

I think there should be a elegant solution for this. Can someone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic case of search and replace.

```
//"sub string" regular expresion
val ssRE = raw"substr\((\w+),\d+,\d+\)".r

val exA = "name,name|substr(city,53,17),coun"
ssRE.replaceAllIn(exA,"$1_tmp")
//res0: String = name,name|city_tmp,coun

val exB = "age,age|substr(zip,10,16),zipcode|substr(street,19,20),place"
ssRE.replaceAllIn(exB,"$1_tmp")
//res1: String = age,age|zip_tmp,zipcode|street_tmp,place
```